# Calculating the beta function of QED through the 1-loop process amplitudes

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-electrodynamics, renormalization, feynman-diagrams, correlation-functions

The beta function for massless QED coupling constant (the electric charge) is usually calculated by, firstly, finding independently the 3 renormalization coefficients of QED -- $Z_1,Z_2$ and $Z_3$, or, equivalently, $Z_e, Z_A, Z_\psi$ -- and then deducing the beta-function through the Callan-Simmanzik equation and an analysis of the matching of divergencies in the equations that arise.

Could we calculate it by simply evaluating, with dimensional regularization, the complete, non-amputated, 1-loop amplitude corresponding to the correct 3-point function, subtracting the infinities through, e.g., the $\overline{MS}$ scheme, defining the coefficient of $\gamma_\mu$ as the electric charge (at some unphysical, off-shell, momentum configuration to avoid complex singularities) and taking its derivative with respect to the arbitrary scale $\log\mu$ to find the beta function?

The diagrams would be the ones below:

[image]

In the case of a negative, I would appreciate any insights regarding what am I missing or misunderstanding regarding the Renormalization Group.

Comment: Comment to the post (v2): One could in principle consider non-1PI diagrams, but why complicate the 1-loop renormalization analysis unnecessarily?

Comment: @Qmechanic thank you for the comment. The point is that a direct, 'one step' analysis like this is, in principle, more straightforward to my purposes than to evaluate the geometric series of 1PI diagrams for each counterterm and then effect the divergencies analysis. I wanna follow a (obviously clear and well understood, but not to me) path where I evaluate the renormalized electric charge directly and merely take its derivative.